# ImportError: cannot import name 'AnsweringMachine' from partially initialized module 'scapy.ansmachine'

Tags: python-3.8

When I use the scapy.layers.inet.IP package, the result shows that
ImportError: cannot import name 'AnsweringMachine' from partially initialized module 'scapy.ansmachine'.

I am confused and this is my python demo.

```py
import hashlib
import time

from scapy.layers.inet import ICMP, IP
from scapy.sendrecv import sr1

SUCCESS = 100001
FAILURE = 100002

def random_str_byte():
    temp = hashlib.md5()
    temp.update(bytes(str(time.time()), encoding='utf-8'))
    result = temp.hexdigest()
    return bytes(result, encoding='utf-8')


def ping(target_ip):
    package = IP(dst=target_ip)/ICMP()/random_str_byte()
    result = sr1(package, timeout=3, verbose=False)
    if result:
        return target_ip, SUCCESS
    else:
        return target_ip, FAILURE


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = ping('XX.XX.XX.XX')
    print(a)
```

The error information is that

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zhaozihao/PycharmProjects/MachineProject/api/PingTest.py", line 6, in <module>
    from scapy.layers.inet import ICMP, IP
  File "/Users/zhaozihao/PycharmProjects/MachineProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scapy/layers/inet.py", line 22, in <module>
    from scapy.ansmachine import AnsweringMachine
  File "/Users/zhaozihao/PycharmProjects/MachineProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scapy/ansmachine.py", line 20, in <module>
    from scapy.sendrecv import send, sniff
  File "/Users/zhaozihao/PycharmProjects/MachineProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 61, in <module>
    import scapy.route  # noqa: F401
  File "/Users/zhaozihao/PycharmProjects/MachineProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scapy/route.py", line 218, in <module>
    conf.route = Route()
  File "/Users/zhaozihao/PycharmProjects/MachineProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scapy/route.py", line 37, in __init__
    self.resync()
  File "/Users/zhaozihao/PycharmProjects/MachineProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scapy/route.py", line 45, in resync
    from scapy.arch import read_routes
  File "/Users/zhaozihao/PycharmProjects/MachineProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scapy/arch/__init__.py", line 124, in <module>
    from scapy.arch.bpf.supersocket import *  # noqa F403
  File "/Users/zhaozihao/PycharmProjects/MachineProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scapy/arch/bpf/supersocket.py", line 27, in <module>
    from scapy.layers.l2 import Loopback
  File "/Users/zhaozihao/PycharmProjects/MachineProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scapy/layers/l2.py", line 17, in <module>
    from scapy.ansmachine import AnsweringMachine
ImportError: cannot import name 'AnsweringMachine' from partially initialized module 'scapy.ansmachine' (most likely due to a circular import) (/Users/zhaozihao/PycharmProjects/MachineProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scapy/ansmachine.py)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Could you give me some suggestions or solutions. Thanks.

Comment: This is due to a circular dependency in scapy. I reproduced the issue. It's looking like an issue against scapy

Answer (score 1):

> from scapy.layers.inet import ICMP, IP

Importing inet directly causes this issue. Instead of that, try importing

> from scapy.all import *

This will bring in ICMP, IP and everything else inside scapy.layers.inet

or

> import scapy.all as scapy

and replace IP with scapy.IP and ICMP with scapy.ICMP